# Outbound Email configuration in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, smtp, outgoing-email

I am trying to connect outbound email in sharepoint 2013. I have added my SMTP IP and email address in outbound email settings but now when i am trying to send email through code, I am getting below error:

> Could not find HostController Service in server xxx.xxx.x.xxx .
>   Skipping the server. Exception : System.ArgumentException: Could not
>   find the ServiceInstance in server xxx.xxx.x.xxx     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchAdminUtils.GetServiceInstancesOnServers[T](IEnumerable`1
>   servers, String notFoundMessage)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchAdminUtils.GetServiceInstanceOnServer[T](String
>   serverName)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Topology.SearchTopologyUtils.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__4(SPServer
>   farmServer)

I checked through telnet it sends email successfully.

Advice me how can i resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on which server you install the SMTP?

Answer (score 0):

This is some kind of know issue, i think it is easy to ignore as long as your Search and emails are working.

Actually, HostController services iterate through all the servers in the farm ( irrespective of their role), like SharePoint servers, SQL servers and email servers..you can get the list of server by running `Get-Spserver` or go to Central Admin > System Settings > Manager Servers in this farm. HostController Services check the HC services on all the server when it could not find it then through this error (which it should not check but it checking).

In your case, if you go to manager server page from central admin then you will see IP address of SMTP server over there.

Comment: My Email is not working If I am trying to send using code